# how to get the focus to a button on pressing the "enter" key in the key board

Tags: asp.net, button, setfocus

i have a aspx page with two buttons,"close" and "submit" button.when i press the enter key in the keyboard the focus automatically goes to "close" button and closes the page.Instead i want the focus to be focused on the "submit" button on pressing  the enter key in the keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set *defaultbutton* property on your frame:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="btnID">
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/985791.aspx